# Scrollable horizontal and vertical table with fixed top and left headers JSF - icefaces

Tags: jsf, datatable, icefaces

I'm facing a problem I can't solve.
I'm using icefaces and mojarra implementation. I want to create a table with fixed header on top and left but scrollable data (horizontal and vertical).

Just to put it simple I want a table similar to an excel environment. If I scroll right the header on the top moves right but the first column remeins fixed, if I scroll down the header on top has to remain fixed but the first column has to scroll down.

I did it with a normal datatable with headers on top and a different table on left. Using jquery, I'm assigning the scroll position of the datatable to the left table, but this is incredibly slow. Moving the scroll up and down the user sees the mismatch between the rows and the left header and after some time the table result aligned again.

There is a way to do that with icefaces without jquery ? Someone told me to use iframe, can anyone help me finding any infos ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can use icefaces ace:datatable component. It has both column pinning, fixed header and footer.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using ice:datatable without the solution, can you provide an example?